# Linq Expression to Organize (sorta like Group By but different)

Tags: c#, linq, collections, generic-programming

Let's say I have a fairly large `IList<foo>` where `foo` looks like this:

```
public class foo
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Territory { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Person { get; set; }
}
```

...is there a way, using a reasonably quick/ efficient expression, to "group" these foo items by `Region`, so I might end up with an `IDictionary<string, IList<foo>>` and have the `string` key be the `Region` property, with each subordinate `IList<foo>` containing only the `foo` records that match that region?  (it would not have to be an `IDictionary`, that's just to illustrate the gist of what I'm trying to do.)  I want to present an interactive list to my MVC view organized this sort of way, without having to write something relatively complex or use a third-party library.

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps I was assuming a GroupBy was like a SQL Group By.  That appears to be incorrect on my part.  Well, I guess that's the answer then!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - you want a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Region);
```

You *can* create a dictionary by grouping, but personally I prefer to use a lookup as it's specifically designed for the "single key, multiple values" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<Foo> foos = //whatever
var groups = foos
    .GroupBy(f => f.Region)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

Comment: Hah so it is GroupBy... I simply assumed that was relative to SQL Server for aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<Foo> foos = //whatever

var groups = foos.ToLookup(f => f.Region);
```

An `ILookup<T>` is like dictionary, but each key references a list of values instead of just one.